# Joining tables in MongoDB with Mongoose in Nodejs Back-End

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am a new student for MongoDB and I have MongoDB Schema called usersSchema.And I need to join this Schema with incomeSchema.

This is my usersSchema :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const usersSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        pnumber: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
const Users = mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema);
module.exports = Users;
```

And I need to join usersSchema email with my incomeSchema.And I can't find out how to join this two Schema with single unique data.

This is my incomeSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const incomeSchema= new Schema(
    {
        income: {
            type: double,
            required: true
        },
        email: { //This is the column I need to join and this colum come from usersSchema 
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },

    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
const Income= mongoose.model('Income ', incomeSchema);
module.exports = Income;
```

Thank You..!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to avoid join(lookup) in mongoDB
2. Check aggregation/$lookup if you still need to join